# anythingslider navigationsize not working on first load firefox 26

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, firefox, anythingslider

I'm having weird problems with anythingslider.js using navigationsize. It's working properly with Chrome, IE, but on FireFox it only shows 1 slide. I checked the code of anythingslider.js and it seems that jquery outerWidth is not working properly on FireFox only on first load of the site. When you refresh it works. Demo here -> http://gen4games.com/softlaunch/

View on FireFox, then on Chrome.

Please help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, that is weird... the problem appears to be that the thumbnail images aren't loaded when the navigationSize width is calculated. I haven't tested this, but setting the thumbnail image width should fix this issue. Try something like this:

CSS

```
.thumb { width: 80px; }
```

Script (just change the `navigationFormatter` to include the above class name)

```
navigationFormatter : function(i, panel){
    return '<img class="thumb" src="images/slides/thumbs/' + ['slide.1', 'slide.2', 'slide.3', 'slide.4', 'slide.5', 'slide.6' /*, 'slide.7' Uncomment to add another video.*/][i-1] + '.jpg">';
},
```

Comment: I already set the width of the image using css hierarchy. Hmm. it's still not working. do you think its a browser issue? I was thinking of putting extra parameters to anythingslider.js to accept the width of the image so it would not be computed via jquery outerWidth. but I think its not a good idea because it wouldn't be dynamic or automatic somehow. this is my last resort. do you have any suggestions? thank you very much!

Comment: The only reason, that I can think of, is that all of the images aren't loaded when the `navigationSize` function determines the widths of the thumbnails because I was only seeing widths of 20px - you can see this in the log if you add the following option: `onInitialized: function(e, slider) { console.log( slider.navWidths ); }`.

Comment: Thanks @Mottie! But I have tried using jquery imagesLoaded plug in before initializing anythingSlider. Any options left I could try? or maybe this is a FireFox issue. what do you think? Thanks! :)

Comment: I don't think it's a problem with Firefox... try [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ycUB6/8002/)